# Unable to Check Radio-button on (click) of another Radio Button: Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

i wan to change the radio button checked status when user clicks on a radio button in another group.

i am trying to do it on click event, when user clicks on one Radio-button.
i am checking for the value and changing the radio-button value in another group.

i have added stackblitz [problem-statement](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1rpoa) link for the same. please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

But i am unable to achieve this

please help.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Getter for form value
this.form.controls.frequency.value = 'freq6'; // Wrong, not working
const value = this.form.controls.frequency.value; // Correct, only for read value
```

This syntax is only for get values, not for set.

To set values please use setter `.setValue()`

In your case: `this.form.controls.frequency.setValue('freq6');`

You can read more about it in documentation. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the value in the controller you have to use controller.setValue().

```
this.form.controls.frequency.setValue('freq6');
```

Your changeFrequency function should be like

```
changeFrequency(event){
    if(event.target.value === "dash2"){
      this.form.controls.frequency.setValue('freq6');
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qph3yb)